# Unable to get AppCompat ActionBar/Toolbar to become an overlay

Tags: android, android-appcompat

So, I have a Toolbar which I'm setting as my supportActionBar, which I want to be in overlay mode. At this point I feel like I've tried everything, but nothing seems to work.

Here's the styles I currently have:

```
<style name="Theme.ArgleBargle" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="vpiIconPageIndicatorStyle">@style/Widget.IconPageIndicator</item>
    <item name="vpiTabPageIndicatorStyle">@style/Widget.TabPageIndicator</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomActionBar" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

And here's the code for my Toolbar:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/actionbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:theme="@style/CustomActionBar"/>
```

And finally, here's where I'm setting it in the Activity:

```
actionbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.actionbar);;
setSupportActionBar(actionbar);
```

I've also tried calling `getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY)` with no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, it turns out the issue was simultaneously totally simple, and yet not obvious (to me, at least). Basically the issue is that although the Toolbar is being set as the Actionbar, it is still at the end of the day a layout element declared in XML. So, the trick is of course to make sure it overlaps in the XML. Here's a sample from my layout, now:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/actionbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

All works as expected now. Hope this can help someone else if they have the same issue!

Comment: android SDK should provide this automatically. also, there is no Standard method of using the the expanded/ collapsing toolbar  shown as standard designs in android lollypop. nightmare being an android developer.

Comment: Correct `RelativeLayout` code should be `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` AFTER `FrameLayout` right? This way the `Toolbar` gets OVER the `FrameLayout`.

Comment: I think the above code may not surface the toolbar because the frame might hide that. You may want to change the order of the frame layout and the toolbar

Comment: I think the order of the frame layout and the toolbar should be swapped, but you don't need the `RelativeLayout` do you? You could just change it for a `FrameLayout`,